# I'm using nebular selector, nb-option are not stick to the nb-select

Tags: angularjs, nebular

Actually I'm using nebular selector, when I click on it a drop down is opened but it is not stick or fixed to that nb-select it is fixed to the webpage and when the page is scrolled the nb-options also getting scrolled with the page

Here is my code I just used the basic nebular selector.
<nb-select size="small" style="width:300px" (selectedChange)="change value()" [(ngModel)]="empselected">
<nb-option value="{{cool}}>